# How to do error analysis/find uncertainty for a Savitzky-Golay filter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, filtering, smoothing

I have put a dataset (x,y) through a Savitzky-Golay filter in Matlab and now I would like to find the uncertainty in x. I have an uncertainty in x pre-filter but not sure if this still stands after smoothing the data. Does anyone know how to do this analysis? Thanks.
The Savitzky-Golay filter I used is
`smoothdata(y,"sgolay","SmoothingFactor",0.1,"Degree",20);`